# How to modify dictionary values based on an array having key information

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict ={'A':{'x':'123','y':'322','z':'432'},'B':{'x':'24','y':'622','z':'5652'},'C':{'x':'424','y':'682','z':'52'},'D':{'x':'32','y':'96','z':'3'}}
```

`arr1 = ['A','B','D']`

values of key to changed: y,z

I want to change dict value(x,y) based on `arr1` such that value of 'y' should be equal to 'z'

Required Dict

`dict ={'A':{'x':'123','y':'322','z':'322'},'B':{'x':'24','y':'622','z':'622'},'C':{'x':'424','y':'682','z':'52'},'D':{'x':'32','y':'96','z':'96'}}`

Comment: Do you have any code that didn't work as you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

You can you can iterate over the elements of `arr1` then set the value of the `z` key.

```
dict1 ={'A':{'x':'123','y':'322','z':'432'},'B':{'x':'24','y':'622','z':'5652'},'C':{'x':'424','y':'682','z':'52'},'D':{'x':'32','y':'96','z':'3'}} 
arr1 = ['A','B','D']

for i in arr1:
    dict1[i]['z']=dict1[i]['y']
print(dict1)
```

---

PS: **Don't use keywords like `dict` as variables because they shadow the inbuilt functions**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use dict as the name for your dictionary, it is a reserved built-in function name.

Where d is your dictionary:

```
for k in arr1:
    d[k]['z'] = d[k]['y']
```

This simply copies the 'z' value of each inner dictionary for each 'y' value.